# Common Lisp: Undefined function k

Tags: common-lisp

I'm pretty new to Common Lisp. And I try to build my own operator functions.
In the first function I tried to add one to the given number. 
The second function we do a recursive use of the first in the frequency of m. 
When I enter totaladd ( 5 3 ) I expect an 8.
What can I do about the undefined funciton k?

```
(defun add1(n)
    (+ n 1)
    )

(write (add1 5))

(defun totaladd (k m)
    (if (eq m 0)
        0
        (totaladd(add1(k) (- m 1)))
    )
)

(write (totaladd 5 3))
```

Comment: why do you write (k)  ?

Comment: @RainerJoswig You are right! I really missed the syntax of function + parameter. Well I took the paranthesis away. Now I get an "add1 should be a lambda expression problem"

Comment: Do not use EQ for numbers, that might not work as you expect. Prefer `=` for numbers. Careful about negative m.

Comment: @coredump That's a nice tip! But doesnt change the lambda problem.

Comment: you might need to edit your question to show us what your code really is. Remember: functions need the right number of arguments. `k` is not a function. `add1` is a function and the syntax for a function call is `(functionname argument1 .. argumentn)`

Comment: Note that the language is called Common Lisp, not CLISP. There is an implementation of Common Lisp called CLISP, though.

Comment: You have another problem because the function will always return zero. Can you spot why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun add1 (n) (+ n 1))

(defun totaladd (k m)
  (if (= m 0) 
      k 
      (add1 (totaladd k (- m 1)))))
```

There is a extra function for `(= ... 0)` called `zerop` which asks whether a number os zero or not. Very frequently used when recursing over numbers as the break condition out of the recursion.
There is also an extra function for `(- ... 1)` or `(+ ... 1)` because these are common steps when recursing with numbers: `(1- ...)` and `(1+ ...)`, respectively.
(Their destructive forms are `(incf ...)` and `(decf ...)`, but these are not needed for recursion.)

So, using this, your form becomes:

```
(defun totaladd (k m)
  (if (zerop m)
      k
      (add1 (totaladd k (1- m)))))
```

Comment: I'd expect `(totaladd (add1 k) (1- m))`.

Comment: EQ is not for comparing numbers. Use EQL or =.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Thank you! True! Corrected.

Answer (score 5):

There are three errors in the next line:

```
(totaladd(add1(k) (- m 1)))
```

Let's look at it:

```
(totaladd                 ; totaladd is a function with two parameters
                          ;  you pass only one argument -> first ERROR
  (add1                   ; add1 is a function with one parameter
                          ;  you pass two arguments -> second ERROR
    (k)                   ; K is a variable, but you call it as a function,
                          ;   but the function K is undefined -> third ERROR
    (- m 1)))
```